# In matplotlib 2.0, how do I revert colorbar behaviour to that of matplotlib 1.5?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I just upgraded to matplotlib 2.0 and in general, I'm very happy with the new defaults. One thing which I'd like to revert to the 1.5 behaviour is that of `plt.colorbar`, specifically the yticks. In the old matplotlib, only major ticks were plotted on my colorbars; in the new matplotlib, minor and major ticks are drawn, which I do not want.

Below is shown a comparison of the 1.5 behaviour (left) and the 2.0 behaviour (right) using the same colormap and logarithmic ticks.

[image: A comparison of colorbar yticks]

What defaults do I need to set in `matplotlibrc` in order to revert to the 1.5 behaviour shown on the left? If there is no way to do this using `matplotlibrc`, what other avenues are available for altering this globally beyond downgrading to matplotlib 1.5?

I have tried simply setting `cbar.ax.minorticks_off()` after every instance of `cbar = plt.colorbar(mesh)`, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be sufficient to just set the colorbar `locator` to a [`LogLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator) from the [`matplotlib.ticker`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module, and then call [`update_ticks()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase.update_ticks) on the colorbar instance.

For example, consider this minimal example which produces the colorbar you are seeing with minor ticks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Some random data in your range 1e-26 to 1e-19
data = 10**(-26. + 7. * np.random.rand(10, 10))

p = ax.imshow(data, norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=1e-26, vmax=1e-19))

cb = fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If we now add the following two lines before calling `plt.show()`, we remove the minor ticks:

```
cb.locator = ticker.LogLocator()
cb.update_ticks()
```

[image]

Alternatively, to achieve the same thing, you can use the `ticks` kwarg when creating the colorbar, and set that to the `LogLocator()`

```
cb = fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax, ticks=ticker.LogLocator())
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! While this does appear to work on a case-by-case, and I'll accept it as an answer in a day or two if nobody has a better one, it requires an extra kwarg every time I plot a colorbar which is logarithmic.

I'm still hopeful (perhaps foolishly) that there's a global fix for this issue which means I can just call a single function and get a good colorbar regardless of whether my data's logarithmic or not.